# Generating require-clauses with Racket macros

Tags: macros, metaprogramming, racket, language-extension

Okay, I must be really daft. I'm trying to create a macro (part of a larger undertaking) that given a function, wraps it in its own submodule, then `require`s it, so that functions defined thusly cannot mess around with surrounding terms, but that the rest of their host module can use them as normal. Perhaps this isn't a good idea, but humour me – I cannot see why it should be impossible.

I've got the following minimal code example, in two files.

**tinylang.rkt:**

```
(provide (all-defined-out))

(define-syntax (modularise stx)
  (syntax-case stx ()
[(_ func)
 (with-syntax ([mod (datum->syntax stx 'testmodule)]
               [nm  (datum->syntax stx 'working)]
               )
   #`(begin

       (print (list "Defining module " 'mod))(newline)

       (module mod racket
         (provide nm)
         (define  nm func)
       )

       (require (for-syntax (submod "." mod))) ;; at least kills a syntax error
       (require (for-template (submod "." mod))) ;; doesn't help
    ))]))
```

**tinyimp.rkt:**

```
#lang racket
(require "tinylang.rkt")
(modularise (lambda () (display "this works!")))
; the following line would make everything work!
;(require (submod "." testmodule))
(working)
```

I feel guilty about spamming this site with questions which I feel should be trivial for me to solve with the documentation, but it's still not clear for me what happens at what stage. If someone knows a good resource (book, lecture, paper) I'd be really happy to hear about it.  I know about the Racket documentation, which is really extensive, but often I miss the crucial details in the explanations there.

Comment: Although I don't know if you'll find it helpful, I wrote [Fear of Macros](http://www.greghendershott.com/fear-of-macros/).

Comment: Okay, my intuition of the problem is that the syntax/identifier `nm` is being created with lexical info which places it outside of the new module `mod`, sort of. Maybe I'm wrong. Either way I have no idea how to fix this.

Comment: @GregHendershott, right, I'd stumbled upon that – will pay it some more attention. Thanks for the pointer, perhaps I should work through it thoroughly.

Comment: Your question has me stumped. Because it's related to a question I saw on users@racket-lang.org last week, I [posted a message there](http://lists.racket-lang.org/users/archive/2013-September/059537.html) just now.

Comment: I mentioned this in your other post, but Matthew Flatt's recent Clojure/West talk explains a lot about Racket's macros (though perhaps not this exact issue): http://www.infoq.com/presentations/racket

Comment: Indeed I've already watched that presentation twice, but I don't think I understand 100% of the details. It gets better every time, though :) Thanks for the pointers, @stchang and @Greg!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, macro-generated requires and provides are tricky. They key is the lexical scope of the require-spec (ie the `(submod "." testmodule)`).

From the [docs](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/syntax-model.html?#%28part._macro-introduced-bindings%29):

> In require ... the generator of the require-spec determines the scope of the bindings.

In other words, the require-spec and the uses of required identifiers must have the same scope.

Here is a version of tinylang.rkt that will work:

```
#lang racket

(provide (all-defined-out))

(define-syntax (modularise stx)
  (syntax-case stx ()
    [(_ func)
     (with-syntax ([require-spec (datum->syntax stx '(submod "." testmodule))])
       #`(begin
           (module testmodule racket
             (provide working)
             (define working func))
           (require require-spec)))]))
```

Comment: Right, I'd indeed already discovered by trial-and-error that the position of the `require` was crucial, so I guess the next logical step is what you propose. Seeing the answers to this and my previous question, I guess that the way to "splice" code is indeed like you're showing, using `with-syntax`. Anyway, thank you very much, once again! I feel as if I haven't RTFM, so I'll try harder to understand what's written down.

Comment: I think learning by-need like you are doing is the way to go and it seems like you already understand most of the fundamentals. Aimlessly reading the docs without a specific goal usually results in not retaining anything, at least for me.